# Mono (in Ubuntu) and visualstudio.com

Tags: ubuntu, tfs, mono, visual-studio-2013

Does it play together? That is: Mono 4.0.12 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS against TFS visualstudio.com?

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 in Windows, with the visualstudio.com TFS. Now I've started looking at Mono in Linux, and I'm wondering if I can work on the same projects as in Windows? This isn't a must, though - the important thing is that I can push my Mono solution/projects to the visualstudio.com TFS.

I see several mentions of it around the web, but I can't seem to find concrete instructions on how to set it up. Anyone?

Update:

I just tried adding TeamAddins. It installed, but when I selected Checkout, and chose Team Foundation Server, I got this error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of 
an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'TeamAddins.VersionControl.TFS.TFSRepository' from assembly 
'TeamAddins.VersionControl.TFS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlSystem.CreateRepositoryInstance () 
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
...
```

Then, nothing.

Update 2:

Now, on a new or existing solution/project, monodevelop crashes every time I either right-click the solution or the project in the explorer window, or click the Version Control top menu entry. Here's the error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of 
an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepositoryReference 
(System.String path, System.String id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepository (IWorkspaceObject 
entry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlCommandHandler.CreateItem (System.Object 
obj, Boolean projRecurse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlCommandHandler.GetItems (Boolean 
projRecurse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.AddinCommandHandler.RunCommand (Commands cmd, Boolean 
test, Boolean projRecurse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.AddinCommandHandler.TestCommand (Commands cmd, 
MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandInfo item, Boolean projRecurse) [0x00000] in 
<filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.AddinCommandHandler.UpdateDiff 
(MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandInfo item) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

...and so on...

And after a complete uninstall, removal and reinstall, monodevelop doesn't even start:

```
Monodevelop failed to start. The following error has been reported:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Forget this. Life's to short to waste on garbage software like this.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [TeamAddins](http://www.teamaddins.com/) or [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240)?

Comment: Team Explorer Everywhere seems to be for Eclipse only? And TeamAddins seems to be for Xamarin Studio, which I've no idea what is. I'm using monodevelop in Linux...

Comment: TeamAddins is for both Xamarin and MonoDevelop. In Mono, go to your add-in manager and add a repository of `http://www.teamaddins.com/monodevelop/4.0/` - That should provide version `3.0.3.0` of `MonoDevelop Add-in for Team Foundation Server`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Right after purging my monodevelop installation because an incorrect git entry completely barfed it.

Comment: After trying the TFS addins, Mono is forever broken for my Ubuntu system. It crashes constantly, and no amount of cleaning is able to get the POS cleaned out of the system. Advice: Stay away, from Mono for linux (monodeveloper) and the TFS addin. There's no help to get from the Mono creators, or anywhere else on the web.